# User's title attribute from Teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a working Teams bot, using the nodejs botbuilder-teams SDK v3, and registered at dev.botframework.com and apps.dev.microsoft.com.  I have created a Teams app that contains it (using the App Studio app in Teams), and installed it in an Office 365 developer tenant of which I am the admin, and the bot can send and receive messages with no problem.

When the bot is added to a team, I get the "conversationUpdate"/"teamMemberAdded" message, and use the fetchMembers() call from the teams bot connector to retrieve basic info for each member, including "givenName", "surname", "email", etc.  However, I don't get the "jobTitle" attribute.  Is there any way to retrieve jobTitle through the Teams bot SDK?

Alternatively, could I make MSGraph API calls (say, /v1.0/groups/{group-id-for-teams}/members)?  Is there a good example of a nodejs serverside app like a bot calling the MSGraph API?  The authentication part seems somewhat murky to me.

Answer (score 0):

**jobTitle** is not part of [roster details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#rest-api-example). You need to call Graph APIs to fetch additional details.

Here is [Node.js sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-flow-bot#samples) for bot authentication. If you are using Azure for bot registration then please take a look at [Azure Bot Service for Authentication in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card) documentation.

Comment: This is where the murky part enters for me.  The Bot Authentication flow chart shows a user message triggering a sign-in dialog for that user (and delegated permissions?), where I was thinking in terms of application permissions and somehow getting credentials for MSGraph based on my app's ID and secret (a ["confidential" client?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#client-application)).  I'll have to dig into OAuth and that bot authentication stuff to wrap my head around what's there.

Comment: If you could get admin consent for your app then you can easily use [application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) to call Graph APIs in your bot code.

Comment: Ah, perfect, I think that's exactly what I was looking for.  My bot is registered at https://dev.botframework.com/bots, and as a bot migration to Azure is not required.  I can set the requested application permissions (such as User.Read.All), but I'm not sure    if installing the bots Teams manifest in Teams (as the tenant admin) provides the necessary admin consent.  I'll dig back into this again tonight, thanks.